# base32 with included forward error correction (FEC)?

Tags: hamming-code, base32, forwarderrorcorrection

I am trying to find (or pipe together) a way to encrypt text so that the output is base32 encoded *and* protected by forward error correction against lost characters.

Having some some `base32` output like `NBSWY3DPEB3W64TMMQXAU===` I would like to transmit it, and even if `NBS_Y3D_EB3W_TMMQXAU===` is received ("_" = missing character) or `NISWY3DZEB3W6WTMMQXQU===` is received (wrong characters) I'd like a correct de-`base32` that I can then pipe to my decryption.

In detail:

This is for a purely hypothetical situation in which I must transmit an encoded message via telephone, shortwave or any other spoken text or morse channel. I.e. nothing "digital" that can handle >5 bit text. On the other side, a human will pick up and transcribe the message and then feed it into a computer for decryption.

I've tried `openssl enc -e -aes256 -k "12345" -nosalt -pbkdf2|base32` (`-nosalt` just for human eyed verification of repeated attempts), but that doesn't have any FEC.

Piping the `openssl`-output into some FECing tool (`redupe`, `fecsum`, `par2`) and then `base32`ing  the result yields unsuable FEC as base32 doesn't like any characters to be missing.

The output of the FECing tools that I know produce no base32 output. And here I stand, basically looking for a base32 implementation that is hardened by an included FEC mechanism (LDPC, Hamming codes etc.).

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like you have to do FEC yourself on 5 bits words. Are you sure this is not some programming task?

Comment: @JoopEggen  I'm 47 and working in a completely different field - no, it is not ;)

Comment: Sorry, but it is that if a "digit" is _dropped entirely_ or _some bits altered_ (hamming say `%` instead of `E`, 2 bits; or `§`/ `G`) then 5 bits are concerned, so it does look to me very specific programming is needed. Upvoted your question